# Android Fragment not updated

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using the following code to show/hide the ad banner:

```
private void showAd(boolean show) {

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if ( show ) {
        Log.d(TAG,"show ad");
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .show(m_adFragment)
                .commit();
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG,"hide ad");
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .hide(m_adFragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

After user purchase to unlock, the ***showAd(true)*** will be called (it is called based on my log). The problem is the ad banner fragment is still shown until I goto other activity and come back.

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing in my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Call *.executePendingTransactions();* after the *.commit()*.

Commit doesn't actually execute it schedules the transaction to be performed. Manually executing isn't usually necessary but it sounds like you may have something that's interfering with the commit on the UI thread.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The .commit is called. But after .executePendingTransactions() the fragment is still not updated.

Comment: Have you tried using .remove instead of just hiding it? Is there a reason you want it to remain in the view hierarchy?

Comment: I'll have a try on .remove(). Thanks

Comment: I think it might be important to look at when you load the Activity again after this mechanism has occurred and you are coming back from anther activity are you just not adding the fragment or are you changing its visibility.

Comment: The fragment is created inside the layout. I'm checking the status of something else (for example, the **Unlock** status) to decide whether I should show it or hide it inside the **onCreate** on my activity. (The **Unlock** is correct and I did call the **hide** function.)